# Unable to create ember.js project

Tags: git, ember.js, npm, mozilla

I've been trying to create a new `ember.js` project via cmd all I keep getting is this error

```
Failed to execute 
   git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit-builds.git
exit code of #128 </strong><br/><br/>
```

How would you avoid that error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be because the protocol git (using the port 9418) is blocked in your case.

You can instruct git to use https instead of git with:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```